# Complex expression repeating vs subquery in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have such dilemma writing:

```
SELECT CASE Complex_Multiline_Condition WHEN THEN ... END as some_field,
       <a_lot_of_fields> 
  FROM a
  JOIN b ON Complex_Multiline_Condition
```

or

```
SELECT CASE cond_result WHEN 1 THEN ... ELSE ... END as some_filed,
       <a_lot_of_fields>  
  FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN Complex_Multiline_Condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as cond_result, 
      <a_lot_of_fields>  
      FROM a      
  )
  JOIN b ON CASE cond_result WHEN 1 THEN ELSE END = ...
```

Second way is more clear and DRY, but introduces one more step in processing. This is important for me, because I'm dealing with huge dataset (about million records). So what is general rule of thumb in this situation? Does subquery COST a lot to re-select huge dataset in subquery only for complex condition evaluation?

Comment: Have you compared the two statements' execution plans? I'd say go with second version, don't write same Complex_Multiline_Condition twice, too easy to make mistakes, especially when someone else need to adjust it later.

Comment: I haven't compared yet, because think that plan cost value is so relative. Just wanted some consultation in theoretical manner

Comment: A milion recrods is not huge dataset, and as it looks I think both query will run quickly .

Comment: This is simplified version of query. Complex condition is repeatedly used in  several expressions. Ok I'll try to estimate both versions' execution time and feel the difference

Comment: I, too, would go with the second query. The optimizer should make the same execution plan for both queries anyhow (i.e. notice that the same CASE expression is used twice), so use what is more readable / maintainable, which is query #2 for me.